# Why I have std::invalid_argument stream error when I run my program from an other folder

Tags: c++, gcc, g++, cross-compiling

I cross-compile my program with SysGCC\raspberry\bin\arm-linux-gnueabihf-gdb.exe.
When it's done, I can run my program from its folder (run with ./program) on the remote machine, but if I try to run from an other folder (eg. /project/program), I have exception std::invalid_argument stream error and the program is aborted.

Is someone knows this issue and knows how to workaround ?
If you need more info, let me know.

So I think it's probaly because I load a file, before the main function is executed, within an object Config like this:

```
Config config("config.json");
```

So Can I do this or something like that, or I have to load this file in the main function to get the current working directory ?

Comment: Perhaps because you use files with relative paths inside your program, and you can't open, read from or write to the files when the [working directory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Working_directory) is not what's epxected?

Comment: the issue is somewhere in your code. Please read about [mcve]. Yes, it does require work to create a mre, but it will pay off. In the best case already in the process of creating one you can find the problem yourself.

Comment: You're probably right, I have before the main function CONFIG config("config.json"); So how can I do to change the CWD before.

Comment: Can you rely on `argv [0]` being set to the folder your program resides in on your Raspberry?  If so, you can use that to construct an absolute path for your config file and then use that instead of using a relative path as you are now.  Relative paths are evil in any case, as you have just discovered.

Comment: @JB_DELR You shouldn't change the working directory, you should write the code so it doesn't matter. It's common to store configurations in dotfiles in the home directory, `getenv("HOME")`.

Comment: Ok, I update my post for clarity. So, I have to load this on the main function for both of your solutions, dotfile or argv[0]. As I want to keep all the files in the same place, the folder of my program, argv[0] will be my solution. thanks for all!